# Can a pitcher switch throwing arms at any time during an inning, or in between pitches?

Tags: rules, baseball, pitching

I have been playing baseball my entire life and I just thought of this question... if a pitcher is ambidextrous (can throw with both arms), is he/she able to switch throwing arms in the middle of an inning, game, or in between pitches?

I know that switch-hit batters are allowed to switch to the other side of home-plate at anytime before the pitcher is ready to pitch, but can the pitcher do the same?

Some pitchers like Billy Wagner had custom gloves made that had 6 finger slots so that he was able to use the glove on both hands at any given time, but when he pitched in games it was either left or right and not both.  Also, Billy could throw over 90 mph with both arms.  I mean if you have that god given ability why worry about changing your arm slot to try and trick the batter's view when you could just throw with the other arm?

Comment: While not quite the same question, the accepted answer is the answer to this question.